# Unable to hit click button in popover content

Tags: jquery, angular

I'm trying to implement a popover & inside that a click function, but my click function is not working. Here is my code:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover2"]').popover({
    trigger: 'click',
    placement: "top",
    html: true,
    content: `<div class='input-group input-group-srchAgent' style='margin-bottom:5px;width:255px;'>
        <div class="popover-content popover-srchAgent">`+`</div>
        <span class='input-group-addon' style='color: #a7a7a7; font-size: 18px; font-weight:normal; border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;border-top-left-radius:20px; border:1px solid #d7d7d7; border-right:0px; padding:6px 12px;width: 50px;height: 44px;'>
            <i class='fa fa-search' aria-hidden='true' ></i>
        </span>
        <input class='form-control provider-search' placeholder='Search' id='partnerAgentSingleSearch' type='text' style='width: 94px;'>
        <select id='getId' title='Provider' class='form-control round provider-select' (change)='changeProviderList($event)' style='width:100px'>
            <option value='myproviders'>MY PROVIDERS</option>
            <option value='all'>ALL</option>
        </select>
    </div>`
})
```

That is my click button, but it is not working:

```
changeProviderList(event) {
    // not working on popover
    console.log(event.target.value, '===========');
}
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: How do you expect angular to know about the popover contents to be able to use `(change)`?

Comment: You would probably have to dynamically create a component instance and bind it to the input group in the popover after it's shown, but I've honestly never tried such a thing.

Comment: What is the option then @AnuragSrivastava

Comment: Something like this might help: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples